# Why does this try/except/else function return None?

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to create a directory. If the name already exists, then it appends "_1" to the directory name recursively.

This runs fine if the directory does not exist already. It also runs fine if the directory already exists (it creates directory+"_1" and returns the same). However, if the directory + "_1" already exists, then the function creates directory+"_1_1" but returns None.

```python
import os

def recurs_mkdir(out_dir):
    try:
        os.mkdir(out_dir)
    except OSError:
        out_dir += "_1"
        recurs_mkdir(out_dir)
    else:
        print "Returning: %s" % out_dir
        return out_dir

>>> print recurs_mkdir("existing_folder")
Returning: existing_folder_1
None
```

Why does it return None in the case of an exception?

EDIT:
Nneoneo's answer works if "exisiting_folder" exists, but does not behave properly if "existing_folder" and "existing_folder_1" exist. Modified, the function is

```python
import os

def recurs_mkdir(out_dir):
    try:
        os.mkdir(out_dir)
    except OSError:
        out_dir += "_1"
        recurs_mkdir(out_dir)
        print "Returning: %s" % out_dir
        return out_dir
    else:
        print "Returning: %s" % out_dir
        return out_dir
```

If "existing_folder" is already created:

```
>>> recurs_mkdir("existing_folder")
Returning: existing_folder_1
Returning: existing_folder_1
existing_folder_1
```

If "existing_folder" and "existing_folder_1" already exist:

```
>>> recurs_mkdir("existing_folder")
Returning: existing_folder_1_1
Returning: existing_folder_1_1
Returning: existing_folder_1
existing_folder_1
```

EDIT 2:
Answer from Nneoneo

```
import os

def recurs_mkdir(out_dir):
    try:
        os.mkdir(out_dir)
    except OSError:
        out_dir += "_1"
        return recurs_mkdir(out_dir)
    else:
        print "Returning: %s" % out_dir
        return out_dir
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact output? I'd expect `returning existing_folder_1` (possibly with some more `_1`s).

Comment: @delnan: You're right, I'm editing the post right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because no `return` statement is invoked at all in case of an exception, the function returns the default value of `None` (this is the same return value you'd get if you wrote a bare `return` statement without a return value).

Add a `return` statement to the `except` clause to return whatever you want.

Comment: No clue, wasn't me. I like your answer, but it doesn't seem to work quite right if, say, you have "existing_folder" and "existing_folder_1" and you run recurs_mkdir("existing_folder").

Comment: What you really need to do is just `return recurs_mkdir(out_dir)`. That way, whatever final directory was *actually* created will be returned by the innermost `recurs_mkdir` call, and passed back up the stack.